# Offshore Bank Account

Tags: scams, international, online-banking

I lent someone some money which they promised to pay back, now I have been asked to open an offshore bank account with a bank called Pub Capital Bank in Mexico which I opened, instead of the money he owed me going into the account he put all his money as well, this bank is also asking for COT payment before allowing me to withdraw my money. Is this legal is the bank legal? Or just another scam.

Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, you have been scammed. It works in stages. The first is they ask for a 'loan' and if you give them any money they have you on the hook. The second stage is to try to make you pay even more money for a 'COT code'. There is no such thing, it's always a scam if you are asked to get one. The money you thought you had 'lent' has if fact been stolen (you won't get it back). Don't pay any more.

Comment: https://money.stackexchange.com/search?q=COT+code

Comment: If you pay for the useless 'COT code', then they say you must pay a transfer fee, then tax, and so on, until either you realise you are being scammed, or else you have no money left.

Comment: Thank you it is as I feared.